# NHibernate and SQLite: will an IgnoreCase() query be an indexed lookup or not?

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, indexing

The Foo column is defined as "Foo TEXT unique". Will an Eq().IgnoreCase() query use the index or will it perform a complete column scan?

The query:

```
string foo = "foo";
IList<T> list = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).
    Add(Expression.Eq("Foo", foo).IgnoreCase()).List<T>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What IgnoreCase does is convert the property and parameter to lower case.